# How to create a new contenttreewidget for z3cform

Tags: plone, z3c.form

I'm trying to override the widget used for relateditems (dexterity so z3cform) which is the from plone.formwidget.contenttree.widget import MultiContentTreeWidget

The issue I have is I don't understand why my example try to find a component to IDataConverter where there is no IDataConverter for contenttree widget and it's parent.

The code is:

```py
#zope
from zope import interface
import z3c.form.interfaces
import z3c.form.widget
from Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile import ViewPageTemplateFile

#plone
from plone.formwidget.contenttree.interfaces import IContentTreeWidget
from plone.formwidget.contenttree.widget import MultiContentTreeWidget
from plone.app.relationfield.widget import RelationListDataManager

#internal


class DatalistManager(RelationListDataManager):
    pass


class IMultiDatalistWidget(IContentTreeWidget):
    """Datalist widget marker for z3c.form """


class MultiDatalistWidget(MultiContentTreeWidget):
    interface.implementsOnly(IMultiDatalistWidget)
    input_template = ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/datalist_input.pt')

    klass = u'html5-datalist-multiselection-widget'
    js_template = """\
    (function($) {
        $().ready(function() {
            console.log('autocomplete ready ?');
        });
    })(jQuery);
    """

    def js_extra(self):
        return ""


@interface.implementer(z3c.form.interfaces.IFieldWidget)
def MultiDatalistFieldWidget(field, request):
    """IFieldWidget factory for DatalistWidget."""
    return z3c.form.widget.FieldWidget(field, MultiDatalistWidget(request))
```

And the zcml:

```xml
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:z3c="http://namespaces.zope.org/z3c"
    i18n_domain="collective.z3cform.html5widgets">

    <include package="plone.app.relationfield" />

    <!--  TRY TO OVERRIDE IRelationList default from plone.app.relationfield -->

    <adapter factory=".widget_datalist.MultiDatalistFieldWidget"
           for="z3c.relationfield.interfaces.IRelationList
                .layer.Layer"
           />

</configure>
```

If I'm trying the widget I have the following traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module plone.z3cform.layout, line 66, in __call__
  Module plone.z3cform.layout, line 50, in update
  Module z3c.form.form, line 208, in update
  Module plone.z3cform.patch, line 21, in BaseForm_update
  Module z3c.form.form, line 150, in update
  Module z3c.form.form, line 134, in updateWidgets
  Module z3c.form.field, line 277, in update
  Module z3c.formwidget.query.widget, line 183, in update
  Module z3c.formwidget.query.widget, line 230, in updateQueryWidget
  Module z3c.form.browser.checkbox, line 45, in update
  Module z3c.form.browser.widget, line 170, in update
  Module z3c.form.widget, line 221, in update
  Module z3c.form.widget, line 130, in update
TypeError: ('Could not adapt', <MultiDatalistWidget 'form.widgets.relatedItems'>, <InterfaceClass z3c.form.interfaces.IDataConverter>)
```

You can find the repository on github: https://github.com/toutpt/collective.z3cform.html5widgets

Answer (score 0):

I once overrode the widget with this class to enable an upload ability for a webmailer. I think you want to override the generation of the json to make this jQuery compatible. Thanks a lot for that work.

Here is my class: http://pastie.org/7923172

Hope it helps.